# Adding key value pair (value from an array) is undefined. What am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to add a key-value pair to an object in the array 'allIcos'. When I console log console.log(tgram) it's an array populated with floats but when I console.log(result) the telegram value is 'undefined' in all the objects in results. Where am i going wrong?

```
  var allIcos = Object.assign(ico.results);
  let tgram = []
  var result = []

  for (let i = 0; i < allIcos.length; i++) {
axios.get(`https://api.telegram.org/chat_id=@${tgramUrl[allIcos[i]}`)
    .then(response => {
      return tgram.push(response.data.result);
          })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  console.log(tgram);
  result = allIcos.map((o,i) => ({...o, telegram: tgram[i]}));
  this.setState({data: allIcos});
  console.log(result);
```

}

Comment: Your request that does the push when it resolves is asynchronous, your console.log is synchronous.

Comment: you need to use `promise.all`, and do setState inside that.

Comment: Thanks man, I thought that might be it. any chance you could show me how to use promise.all in my code?